# What does "Do you know what" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm reading *The Witcher - The Last Wish*

The witcher was asking the castellan about a proclamation, and the castellan told him:

> “Right. Do you know what, Geralt? This”—Velerad slapped the proclamation—“let it go. It's a serious matter. Many have tried and failed already..."

What does the castellan's word "Do you know what" mean?

It looks strange to me. I can't get the castellan's mood precisely since I don't know if it's "Do you know" or "You know what" or "What do you know" or "Do you know what is this" or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fairly common idiom in informal speech for introducing a new idea.

"Do you know what [has just occurred to me]? We won't make the proclamation after all." (I assume that is what 'let it go' means.)

Comment: It could be used to signify that a statement is forthcoming - person A: "If we are late for school, the teacher will be angry." person B: "You know what? I don't care!" (The 'do' at the start is frequently omitted, in informal speech, and sometime the 'you' as well).